# heroku db:push taps wrong ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using OSX Mountain Lion and trying to db:push.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]
$ bundle exec heroku db:push --confirm ancient-falls-9918
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Auto-detected local database: mysql2://root@127.0.0.1/lottery_portal_development?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the app 'ancient-falls-9918' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
/Users/psmy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@lpr31/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Abort trap: 6
```

Why is it trying to use 1.8.7?

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

ree-1.8.7-2011.03 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled heroku and taps at both the project and global level. I have removed any traces of the built in version of ruby (I think).

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @Tony Yes, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28634088/380607

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This might or might not break stuff. This is what I did to fix the problem for me.*

Try this [solution.](http://josediazgonzalez.com/2012/07/25/upgrading-from-lion-to-mountain-lion/)

Uninstall RVM:

```
rvm implode
sudo rm -r ~/.rvm
```

Install rbenv

```
brew update
brew install rbenv
brew install ruby-build
rbenv install 1.9.3-p194
rbenv global 1.9.3-p194
```

Add this to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Install bundler

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Install gems

```
bundle install
```

Re-install the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)

Close all terminal windows and re-open them. I did all of that and db:pull is working again.

Comment: That's the only solution I could find for now. Good luck though.

Answer (score 0):

Because you tried using `bundle exec heroku`. Use just `heroku` instead, that should fix it.

If you want to set the Ruby that the Heroku CLI uses to the one that you've specified with RVM, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28632883/380607