# Rails - "heroku db:push" command failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku

I'm trying to push my app up to the production env on heroku from my dev environment. Ive transferred all my code using

```
git push heroku master
```

Now I need to push my database and Im trying this

```
heroku db:push
```

But its failing and Im getting this message at console.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194@app0907api @~/Documents/myapp06     
>heroku db:push
/Users/hj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@app0907api/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

This is a bit strange since my app uses postgres for dev and production and test, I haven't used sqlite at all neither have I installed any gems for sqlite3

What could be going wrong?

---

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org/'

 gem 'rails', '3.2.8'



 gem 'rails-api'

 gem 'pg'

 gem 'taps'

 gem 'thin'

 gem 'foreman'

 gem 'rabl'



 gem 'paperclip', '~>3.2.0'
 gem 'aws-sdk', '~>1.3.4'

 group :development do

 gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0"
 gem 'debugger'
 end
```

---

SOLUTION FOUND:

Typed in the following line on my terminal console:

```
 gem install heroku
 sudo gem install taps
```

this allowed me to run the command:

```
heroku db:push
```

...but now, while sending the db, I'm getting this error:

```
 Saving session to push_201209202159.dat..
 !!! Caught Server Exception
 HTTP CODE: 500
 Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR: time zone displacement out of range: "2012-09-18 12:00:00.000000+5894853600"
 LINE 1: ...ated_at") VALUES (45, '37.785834', '-122.406417', '2012-09-1...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: Functionality to import/export PG data is now part of the CLI as [heroku pg:push and heroku pg:pull](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull)**

I'd highly recommend the use of the [pg:transfer](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer) plugin for the Heroku CLI. You can do many things with the plugin including [transferring data from your local environment up to the Heroku environment](http://www.ryandaigle.com/a/pgtransfer-is-the-new-taps).

`db:push` and `db:pull` are very fragile for just transferring between two postgres databases.  To transfer from local to remote do the following to install the plugin and transfer the data:

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer
$ heroku pg:transfer --from $DATABASE_URL --to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE_URL
```

The `--from $DATABASE_URL` flag says to pull from the env variable `DATABASE_URL` as the local db location and push to your Heroku app's `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE_URL` database. You can find your Heroku database name using `heroku config`:

```
$ heroku config | grep POSTGRES
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE_URL: postgres://ads8a8d9asd:al82kdau78kja@ec2-23-23-237-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/resource123
```

Comment: but how do i transfer mysql or sqllite databases?

Answer (score -1):

You might have missed out some steps.

1. `bundle install`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m 'your commit message goes here'`
4. `git push heroku`
5. `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Also:

1. `sudo gem install heroku`
2. `sudo gem install taps`

Edit:

To solve rest:

`$ rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p318`
`$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p318`
`$ heroku db:push`

Comment: Hi Thanks. 
I have tried these steps, however the problem is related to this post:
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118173/heroku-dbpush-taps-wrong-ruby" here I think. But the post doesnt  have answers that work.

Comment: You seem to be missing out `sqlite` in `group :development`. Do try out my updated answer Leah.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that but it didn't work. Also, I don't think using sudo with RVM is a good practice.

Comment: It depends. Some systems require `sudo`, some don't.