# How to fix "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a Ruby project, but when running `bundle update` and `bundle install` it returns an error:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

An image of it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/awxw8.png

My gemfile is:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

Comment: Please don't use images or offsite storage for essential parts of your question. Links rot and break. At that point the question will make no sense to future people searching for similar solutions. Instead, copy and paste the salient parts of the error and your gemfile into the question's text.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you run `ruby -v` you're going to see that you've installed Ruby 1.9.3, but the first line in your Gemfile specifies that you want to use Ruby 2.0.0.

You should either install Ruby 2.0.0 or change the first line in your Gemfile to specify Ruby 1.9.3.

sample of Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'pry'

gem 'pry-nav'

# Use with command-line debugging, but not RubyMine
#gem 'debugger'

gem 'bundler'
```

Comment: ur Gemfile specified 2.1.0
~/projects/site (newtemplate) $ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]
~/projects/site (newtemplate) $rails -v
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0
~/projects/site (newtemplate) $rails s
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0
~/projects/site (newtemplate) $bundle exec rails s
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0
How do i solve this?

Comment: I use rvm, and `ruby -v` shows my ruby version is 2.2.0, but the error message says the ruby version is 2.0.0

Comment: @mistertim's answer below fixed this problem for me `$ gem install bundler`

Answer (score 173):

I've noticed this happening when I've tried to `bundle install` with a fresh RVM gemset that didn't yet include bundler (as it fell back on the system bundler install which referenced the system ruby).

Running `gem install bundler` fixed for me.

Comment: remember "rbenv rehash" after "gem install bundler"

Comment: After running "gem install bundler", the problem still exists. Then I reloaded "bashrc" file and it finally worked.

Comment: Probably obvious, but just to add that you need to actually run `bundle` after installing the bundler gem. (Otherwise the error can still occur, due to previously created binaries, which could mislead people to thinking it didn't work.)

Answer (score 40):

None of these worked for me, but I finally figured it out:

```
spring stop
```

I had a Rails 4 project that uses something called Spring to keep a Rails environment running in the background, for speed.

I had started Spring with Ruby 2.1.1 but then I upgraded to 2.1.2 (in Gemfile and .ruby-version). My theory is that Spring kept on running on 2.1.1 and so caused this error.

Comment: This worked for me after I installed Spree, then updated my Ruby version. Thank you.

Answer (score 29):

**Heroku Toolbelt** may be causing it if you are using the `heroku` command, or more specifically, using `bundle exec heroku`, which you should never do. If you can fix your problem by removing `bundle exec` in front of your `heroku` calls, then try that first. If not, then follow what is suggested below.

---

Update February 25, 2017:
**Heroku Toolbelt have been renamed to Heroku CLI**. See these links for updated install/uninstall instructions:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli
https://github.com/heroku/cli

Original post is provided unedited below (for legacy instructions):

---

### If you have installed the Heroku toolbelt from the official site:

At the top of `/usr/bin/heroku` it probably says something like `#!/usr/local/heroku/ruby/bin/ruby`

Try running `/usr/local/heroku/ruby/bin/ruby -v` and see if it outputs ruby 1.9.3.

https://github.com/heroku/toolbelt/issues/53

```bash
› heroku --version
heroku-toolbelt/3.26.1 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

Notice the 1.9.3 specified at the end there.

--- Do **NOT** use this page, and its packaged installer, to install the Heroku CLI on OSX:

https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Because the technical details listed there are important:

> The heroku command line client will be installed into /usr/local/heroku and  /usr/local/heroku/bin will be added to your PATH.

This is detrimental, because RVM will then do this:

```
› rvm current
ruby-2.1.1

› heroku --version
heroku-toolbelt/3.26.1 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

There is that irritating 1.9.3 version, even when I've specified another Ruby version with RVM.

### Uninstall the Heroku toolbelt

There is no official uninstaller for OSX, write +1 here if you think there should be one: https://github.com/heroku/toolbelt/issues/8

Uninstall manually (moving to Trash, to keep a backup, in case something fails):

```
mv ~/.heroku ~/.Trash
sudo mv /usr/local/heroku ~/.Trash
sudo mv /usr/bin/heroku ~/.Trash
```

### Install the Heroku toolbelt with homebrew instead

Because it links the current RVM version to the Heroku-toolbelt correctly. Run:

`brew install heroku-toolbelt`

Heroku toolbelt will then be installed only in this location:

`/usr/local/Cellar/heroku-toolbelt/3.21.4`

(You could also remove it easily with `brew uninstall heroku-toolbelt` if you wanted.)

Testing the install:

```bash
› rvm current
ruby-2.0.0-head@bloggery

› rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-head [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1-head [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

› rvm use ruby-2.1.1
Using /Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1

› rvm current
ruby-2.1.1

› heroku --version
heroku-toolbelt/3.26.1 (x86_64-darwin12.0) ruby/2.1.1
You have no installed plugins.

› rvm use ruby-2.0.0-head
Using /Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head

› heroku --version
heroku-toolbelt/3.26.1 (x86_64-darwin13.4.0) ruby/2.0.0
You have no installed plugins.
```

Notice it now says 2.0.0 at the end of that last command there. You now run the Heroku client with whatever `rvm current` ruby version you have specified in RVM.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. Note that this works the same with rbenv.

Comment: This is fantastic, I was having this exact problem. One comment - your issues link no longer works.

Comment: Thanks @mattnedrich, I updated the post with some new links at the top to the new location on github: https://github.com/heroku/cli

Comment: Only thing that worked for me! Was indeed the old heroku toolbelt that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 11):

If you type `rvm list` and it shows a 2.0 version of Ruby as your current version and you are still getting this error, typing `rvm use (ruby version)` fixed this issue for me.

Comment: this solution works excellent for me, because i'm working multiple projects which is using different ruby version.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a Ruby version manager like RVM or rbenv, then create, in the top-level directory of your project, a file named `.ruby-version` containing the version spec'd in your Gemfile, e.g.:

```
2.0.0
```

That apparently is the cross-`{rbenv,rvm}` way of spec'ing the version now.

Answer (score 5):

"I had the same problem using rbenv, installed via brew.

I couldn't figure it out, tried all of the above, I ended up switching to rvm which solved it."

In response to this post, you have to make sure you run `rbenv rehash` after you install a ruby version. That seemed to work for me when I ran into the same problem.

Comment: Running `rbenv rehash` did solve the problem for me too.

Comment: Woah, I didn't expect to scroll that far to get the answer I was looking for :) I didn't want to move to rvm.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I used `rvm get head` to update the RVM version and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

[ruby-switch was removed from ubuntu 14.04 and up](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/ruby-switch). I'll leave this answer for posterity, but you probably need a different solution. Check out "[Install ruby 2.0 without ruby-switch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452243/install-ruby-2-0-without-ruby-switch)" as well.

---

If you have you've installed a new version of Ruby but are still getting errors about the Gemfile mismatch, you probably need to use `ruby-switch` to set the new version of Ruby as your default:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ruby2.1 ruby2.1-dev
sudo ruby-switch --set ruby2.1
sudo gem install bundler
```

Comment: Nice. `sudo apt-get install ruby-switch` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after upgrading Ruby versions via rbenv. I tried the `spring stop` command that someone mentioned above.

When I ran that I got another message suggesting that I run `gem pristine --all`

> Warning: Running gem pristine --all to regenerate your installed
>   gemspecs will improve the startup performance of Spring.

So I ran that command, and then things went back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

the main reason for this problem is your machine and gemfile using a different ruby version

so there is multiple problems and solutions for this issue you can try the below solutions one by one

1- make sure your machine install and use the same version of your gemfile if your machine not using the same one try to install this version using rvm

```
$ rvm install ruby_version_you_want
```

make sure the version installed success by using this command

```
$ rvm list
```

and if the new version doesn't set as a default you can set it using this command

```
$ rvm --default use ruby_version_you_want
```

you can check the current ruby version

```
 $ rvm current 
 $ ruby -v
```

2- if you have the same issue check your bundler

```
  $ gem install bundler
    or
  $ gem update bundler
```

3- in some cases spring still using the old version so you need to stop it

```
$ ./bin/spring stop
```

4- another case you can type

```
$ gem pristine --all
```

and try to install bundle again

5- also in some cases after install the updated ruby version you just need to restart your terminal.

6- another solution but I didn't recommend it the top-level directory of your project, create a file named .ruby-version containing your active running ruby version

7- if you still have this problem try to remove ruby and install the updated version only

```
 $ aptitude purge ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that reinstalling RVM did the trick when this error occured, as any other suggestion didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue - just a few seconds after watching Mac OSX Terminal confirm that Ruby 2.0.0 was successfully installed.

Mac OSX ships with an out-of-date version of Ruby already installed and set as the default Ruby. In order to correct the issue, you can install "JewelryBox", a charming and lovely app that gives you a GUI to view and manage multiple rubies (helpful if you have multiple dev environments on one Mac). You can use it to deselect Mac OSX's default Ruby and select your newly installed Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using rbenv, installed via Homebrew.

I couldn't figure it out, tried all of the above, so I ended up switching to RVM which solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my rake or rails script under the bin directory was using another version of ruby. I compared two rake scripts from two servers (production and development) and it showed me they were using different ruby versions. So I had to update accordingly.

```
1c1
< #!/usr/bin/env ruby
---
> #!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this error while using the passenger gem. Since I installed this gem with sudo access, it took a default version of ruby on its own. I believe the reason could be that ruby was installed without sudo access on my system and passenger didn't know the actual version of ruby to be used.

However, installing the gem and its apache module without sudo access fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for anybody finding this issue and none of the typical solutions resolve this issue for you, check to see if you have more than one ruby version manager. There are multiple version managers, and some software or install scripts will use different ones. I know of `rbenv`, `rvm`, `asdf`, and at least one other that I don't recall the name of. I had `asdf` installed by a different tool without realizing it happened and it caused the specified version mismatch.

To check for this execute `which ruby` and look carefully at the path. If it's not the actual version manager you are expecting, you are suffering from this issue. Simplest fix is to use the one you want, and get rid of the other one. If for some reason you need to keep both, you will probably need to change the order of paths in your shell's .rc file.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue then found and tried below steps

Step1: `rvm use jruby-9.2.9.0`

Step2: `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because you pull to a new repository, whose binaries are defined in the system, or in its path, and maybe the ruby binaries in this case inside your system are in different directories or they are not within the environment variables of the new repository or application.

that's why it's good to check the path defined in the shebang (`#!/usr/bin`...) of the files inside the "`/bin`" folder, like '`/bin/rails`', '`/bin/rake`', '`/bin/yarn`' etc, as the rails application will use these executables and may default to the one on the system, and some **unixlike** systems have ruby installed by default but it is an old version which may does not work with your rails application

To know which ruby binary you are using, you must use the command `which ruby`, since it shows the interpreter that is being used and its location within the system, or you can also look at the $PATH of the system with the command `echo $PATH | grep ruby`, and see if there is a path to a ruby binary.

and it only remains to update the path in the shebang within the files of the `/bin` folder so that it can work without problem. In my case I have ruby in the environment variables so my shebang would be => `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

Answer (score -1):

I am running the Windows dev environment.

I just added `C:\Ruby22-x64\bin` in my path variable before `heroku\bin` entry.

Answer (score -1):

I share this tidbit in a moment of great relief after having finally solved a problem that's been haunting me for months.

```
rails new myapp
//Your Ruby version is 2.1.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

I tried literally every solution to this problem that I could find on the web and at the end of the day it turns out my problem was caused because I had accidentally installed a Rails app in Users/MyName, and it was reading that Gemfile.

So before you go try the various other solutions offered here, you may want to take a second to confirm that you have not done something similar.