# Rbenv Version 2.1.1, but Error Says Ruby Version is 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ruby-2.0

I'm on Mac/Mavericks, using rbenv and this [rail 4 repo](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4).  My rbenvs version is set to 2.1.0, I uninstalled RVM, but when I type in `ruby -v` it says `ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]` **what do I need to do to make rbenv the default service for my ruby version?**

However, the annoyance is working with my rails app. When I change ruby in my Gemfile to 2.1.1 and bundle install, it says my ruby version is 2.0.0. When I change my version to 2.1.1, it says my Ruby version is 2.0.0.

**What do I need to do to set my ruby version to 2.1.0 so the Gemfile can recognize it?**

[image]
[image]

Bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
PS1='\W \u\$ '

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundler is trying to tell you that the version of Ruby you have loaded is not matching the one you specified in your Gemfile.

`rbenv install 2.1.0 && rbenv local 2.1.0`

Comment: Did that, and when I `bundle install` I get `Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0`

Comment: What if you do the same, but with `2.0.0` instead?

Comment: Trying now, got an error that `rbenv: version 2.0.0 not installed`, however my ruby -v did change to `ruby 2.1.0p0`. Doing `rbenv install 2.0.0-dev` now.

Comment: UPDATE: keep getting this error message `rbenv: version 2.0.0 not installed` any ideas how to get 2.0.0 with rbenv?

Comment: You shouldn't install ruby `2.0.0-dev`, but `2.0.0`.

Comment: `rbenv install 2.0.0` gives me `ruby-build: definition not found: 2.0.0` and list of versions with 2.0.0 in them.

Comment: You might need to update your `ruby-build`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49442/discussion-between-evan-and-aledalgrande)

Answer (score 2):

Was it Spring, maybe? Try `spring stop`

See [How to fix "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342044/in-ruby-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0/24206317#24206317) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually noticed that message showing up if you don't install bundler right off the bat in the new ruby version before trying to perform a **bundle update**.

```
    Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified x.x.x
```

In my case I was moving from the Ruby 2.0 that comes with Mavericks to Ruby 1.9.3p125 with rbenv. I believe the shell will try using whatever *bundle* binary that is available. My solution was just:

```
    gem install bundler
```