# Ruby on Rails does not use the version defined in rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I want to use version 2.2.2 of Ruby, then

```
r2d2@r2d2-acer ~/ApenasMeu/myapp $ rbenv global
system
r2d2@r2d2-acer ~/ApenasMeu/myapp $ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.2.2 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
```

However, the default home page of RoR, it appears that use this version:

> Ruby version   1.9.3-p484 (x86_64-linux)

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bundler you can specify the ruby version in your `Gemfile` - just add a line like `ruby "2.2.2"` to your `Gemfile` (I've always seen it at/near the top - not sure if this is required or just convention) and run `bundle install`.

Comment: In doing so, I get the message `Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2`

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20936316/903163), including the comments - which suggest running `rbenv rehash` after `gem install bundler`