# Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There were so many questions on this topic but none could help me to solve the issue.I am new to ROR. I am trying to run following command

```
rake db:create
```

it throws error though I have ruby 2.2.1 installed and by default it is pointed to

> Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1

I tried running following commands to check which ruby version is being used

```
ubuntu@myserver:~/workspace/railpro/appraiser-events/bin$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
ubuntu@myserver:~/workspace/railpro/appraiser-events/bin$ which ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
ubuntu@myserver:~/workspace/railpro/appraiser-events/bin$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-        2.2.1@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.2.1/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/ usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

This shows that i am using ruby 2.2.1 and in my Gemfile also it points to 2.2.1 but when I use rake db:create it throws this error.

When I tried to change the Gemfile to point to 1.9.3 it said the reverse

> Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3

I tried putting a .ruby-version file in the top level directory and mentioned the 2.2.1 inside that but it didn't work

Comment: From which directory are you trying to run the rake command? What happens if, from the root directory of your app (where your Gemfile sits), try to run `bundle exec rake db:create` ?

Comment: I was executing the command from app-name/bin directory. I tried executing the suggested command from the root directory of the app and it throws the same error
`Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Ruby: "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342044/in-ruby-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0)

Comment: I have gone through all the solutions suggested there but none of the solutions worked for me

Comment: Have you installed rvm? Or rbenv, or any other equivalent?

Comment: yes it's installed. 
`ubuntu@myserver:~$ rvm -v
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
ubuntu@myserver:~$ rbenv -v
rbenv 0.4.0
`

Comment: You have BOTH rvm and rbenv?

Answer (score 1):

Run with [bundle exec](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html):

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

This will ensure that the rake command is executed in the context of the current bundle.

Comment: what's the output of: `bundle exec ruby -v`?

Comment: It gives following output
*ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]*