# Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'
```

and

```
#.ruby-version

2.1.5
```

and this

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.3 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
```

And yet I keep getting this:

```
$ rails s
Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5
```

Ruby 2.1.5 is installed.

```
Already installed ruby-2.1.5.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.5



ruby - v
ruby 2.1.2p95
$ rvm use --default 2.1.5
Using /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
```

But then when I open a new tab or terminal, it reverts back to 2.1.2

```
ruby - v
ruby 2.1.2p95
```

Comment: What is the result of `ruby -v`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Ruby: "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342044/in-ruby-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0)

Comment: can you try typing `rvm use ruby-2.1.5` ?

Comment: @Kiloreux, working but not persistent.

Comment: `rvm --default use 2.1.5` , if you want it to be always this way.

Comment: @Kiloreux, yes, I meant default.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Cool , i will post it as an answer to close this question.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the ruby version just for now , you can choose it by

`rvm use 2.1.5`

And if you want to always be on that version of ruby just type

`rvm --default  use 2.1.5`

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly indicate that you do have another method in your code which setting default ruby-2.1.2 also.

There must be some other file than `.ruby-version` which setting your default ruby version. Due to which your `.ruby-version` file not setting default version for you nor your `Gemfile`.

Look into your application root directory and try find hidden file like `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version` or similar try update or delete that file and then run `rails s`.

After update or delete don't forgot to reopen your application directory. (cd .. and cd /app_directory) Otherwise it won't affect changes.

Comment: He clearly explained that using the rvm default command is sufficient.