# How can I test someone's Rails app cloned from GitHub if I am running a different version of Ruby on my machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

The problem I'm having is that after I clone the repo and try to test the app I get this error- "Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile is specified 2.1.1."

Same error when I run bundle install or try to run the rails server.  Do I need to install the older 2.1.1 version of ruby in order to test the app?

Comment: Use RVM or RBENV so you can have a different version of Ruby in different directories (repos)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Ruby: "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342044/in-ruby-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0)

Comment: I found this guide extremely helpful when I started to work with rvm: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/why-you-should-use-rvm--net-19529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install multiple ruby versions and switch between them using:

1. [rvm](http://rvm.io) -- RVM is a command-line tool which allows you to easily install, manage, and work with multiple ruby environments from interpreters to sets of gems.
2. [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) -- Use rbenv to pick a Ruby version for your application and guarantee that your development environment matches production.

With `rbenv` installed you can invoke:

```
rbenv install 2.1.1
ruby --version #=> 2.1.1
bundle install
```

Now you are ready to test your Rails app with the version intended by the author.

Workflow with `rvm` is very similar.

Comment: When I invoke rbenv install 2.1.1 it says it has installed 2.1.1, but when I check version it hasn't changed strange...

Comment: Installing ruby-2.1.1...
patching file ext/readline/readline.c
patching file ext/readline/extconf.rb
patching file ext/readline/extconf.rb
Installed ruby-2.1.1 to /home/danny/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1

danny@danny-Dell-System-Inspiron-N7110:~$ ruby --version
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a tool like [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/configuration) (Ruby Version Manager) and installing multiple rubies. You can see what rubies are installed with

```
 rvm list rubies
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line in your Gemfile to specify ruby 2.2.3.