# How to enable quiet mode for Postgres commands on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, command-line, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

When using the `psql` command line utility on my local machine, I have the option to use the `-q` or `--quiet` switch to tell Postgres to do it's work quietly - i.e. it won't print every single `INSERT` statement to the console if you're doing a large import.

Here's an example of how I'm using it:

```
psql -q -d <SOME_DATABASE> -f <SOME_SQL_FILE>
```

However, when using the `pg:psql` command line utility in Heroku, that option doesn't seem to be available. So I'm currently having to use it like so:

```
heroku pg:psql DATABASE -a <SOME_HEROKU_APP> < <SOME_SQL_FILE>
```

which produces *a lot* of output to my console (hundreds of thousands of lines), because of the large size of the SQL file I'm importing. Whenever I try to use the `-q` or `--quiet` option, something like this:

```
heroku pg:psql DATABASE -q -a <SOME_HEROKU_APP> < <SOME_SQL_FILE>
```

it'll throw an error saying that `-q` is not a valid option.

Is there some way to enable quiet mode when running Postgres commands in Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

`heroku pg:psql` is just a wrapper onto your local `psql` binary (https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb#L151)

So, given this - you are able to do:

```
psql `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a <yourappname>`
```

to get a psql connection and consequently pass `-q` other options accordingly.

Comment: Thanks John, this is great to know! The only problem with this, for my particular use case, is that I'm using these commands in a rake file. So I need to be able to run one-off commands via `Bundler.clean_system()` instead of opening a connection and manually running commands.