# "Your Ruby version is 2.4.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.0" -- why?

Tags: ruby, heroku

In my .ruby-version and Gemfile the ruby `2.5.0` is specified. When I run "ruby -v", I get "2.5.0". However, when deploying to Heroku, I get this error:

```
    Your Ruby version is 2.4.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.0
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342044/how-to-fix-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0)

Comment: other duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

According to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions#troubleshooting following causes this issue

1. Your bundler version might be old
2. You might have version mismatch between `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 0):

If `ruby -v` is outputting `2.5.0`, you may need to update `Gemfile.lock`. The best way to do that is using bundler.

Check the `Gemfile.lock` file in your project's root to see which version of Ruby it references. It likely will say `ruby 2.4.2`.

Running either `bundle update` or `bundle install` should get your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` matched up again.

Answer (score 0):

At first update The Ruby version installed in your PC/ Laptop (If Any)!!.

Delete the ruby " [version number] " which is written in gemfile,

just Tweak the Version to The Upgraded version installed in your PC ..  <3