# Fail to install bundle ruby version manager

Tags: bash, rvm

I have never tried Ruby before. I am trying to run this [elixirschool github repo](https://github.com/elixirschool/elixirschool).

I first got this error message.

```
$ bundle install  
Your Ruby version is 2.5.1, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.3.7
```

So I follow the instruction from the question. [How to fix "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342044/how-to-fix-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0)

Now I get this message.

```
$ bundle install  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    1: from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)
```

I also did this command.

```
$ bundler install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/bin/bundler:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundler (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Went to https://rvm.io/
- Installed rvm
- In cheatsheet, http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
- `rvm install 2.3.7`
- `rvm use --default 2.3.7`

Comment: I have a similar problem but with windows 10. Do you have any solution or tip because rvm didn´t seems to work with that os? See [my question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144114/cant-find-gem-compass-0-a-with-executable-compass)

Answer (score 1):

Open the gemfile in the root of the folder and delete this:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.2 #or whatever version number you see
```

Then run:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Check:

```
bundle --version
```