# Can't find gem compass (>= 0.a) with executable compass

Tags: node.js, ruby, webstorm, bundler, compass

I can't get PhpStorm to work with a relative installed bundler package.

I´m using bundler with following gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "susy", "~>2.2.14"
gem "sass", "~>3.4.22"
gem "compass", "~> 1.1.0.alpha.3"
gem "breakpoint", "~>2.5.0"
gem "font-awesome-sass", "~>4.6.2"
```

At the PhpStorm terminal I'm executing the following command to install the gems to the relative directory `gems/`:

```
bundle install --path gems/
```

Bundler installed all to the directory `gems/` without any error.

[image: Installed relative ruby folder structure]

My watcher task looks like this:

[image: screenshot watcher].

If I make some changes in my scss file the watcher throws

```
cmd.exe /D /C call "F:\Cloud\Zoho WorkDrive (Gedankenfolger® GmbH)\General\Kunden 2019\Uhlmann\TYPO3\Wonder by Uhlmann TYPO3 87\gems\ruby\2.6.0\bin\compass.bat" compile "F:\Cloud\Zoho WorkDrive (Gedankenfolger® GmbH)\General\Kunden 2019\Uhlmann\TYPO3\Wonder by Uhlmann TYPO3 87\fileadmin\templates"
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem compass (>= 0.a) with executable compass (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
from F:/Cloud/Zoho WorkDrive (Gedankenfolger� GmbH)/General/Kunden 2019/Uhlmann/TYPO3/Wonder by Uhlmann TYPO3 87/gems/ruby/2.6.0/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I get this to work?

System environment:

- Windows 10 Pro / Version 1809 / Build 17763.316
- PhpStorm 2018.3.4
- ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x64-mingw32]
- npm 6.4.1
- bundler 2.0.1

Comment: Have you tried running the same command out of the IDE in the command line? Do you get the same error?

Comment: Output is: Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from F:/Cloud/Zoho WorkDrive (Gedankenfolger® GmbH)/General/Kunden 2019/Uhlmann/TYPO3/Wonder by Uhlmann TYPO3 87/gems/ruby/2.6.0/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem compass (>= 0.a) with executable compass (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't install with such `--path` option. I'd just execute `bundle install`.

(You might want to delete the `.bundle/config` file too first).

Comment: The thing is i want a project specific installation not a global this is why i use the --path option

Comment: My originally reason was to handle different gem versions but i get errors with the newest version of sass and my needed version for this project. Rvm seems a solution but not for windows. Pik is outdated and uru seems also a bit complicated for me. Also the documentation is a bit frustrating.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about global gems installation. You still need to use `bundle exec` in most local installs. Just install without path and execute with `bundle exec` and all should be fine.

Comment: What is `bundle exec` for? I didn´t needed it before. And as i wrote before i had problems with global gems in combination with different version of sass.

Comment: Your problems most likely stemmed from the fact that you didn't use `bundle exec`. Read more about it here: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html or just google for it.

Comment: Thanks in advance. Much to read and understand here. Especially because i do not run a ruby app only sass etc. for precompiling my scss files with a watcher inside phpstorm.

Comment: You thank the users who answer your questions here by upvoting and accepting their answers ;)