# Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a very simple rails program at windows 10, and ran it very ok, then I downloaded it to my computer (win 7), it said to me that `Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.4`

I tried to ran `gem install bundler` , `bundler install` , `gem update bundler`, but nothing changed.

Could you please give me some ideas? I am a newbie and very confuse with this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a file in your project called Gemfile. In there is a line where the ruby version is defined as 2.6.4. You can either change it to 2.6.3 or install Ruby 2.6.4 on your machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342044/how-to-fix-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Ruby 2.6.4 or change your Gemfile from: `ruby "2.6.4"` to `ruby "2.6.3"`